# Using CSS Grid globally in Angular6

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

I am trying to use css grid globally in angulars styles.css file.
It seems elements withing the app component cannot be accessed.
I'm using grid-template-areas, and I am displaying my grid in the body.

styles.css:

```css
       /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
    body{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:"header header header"
                            "main main main"
                            "footer footer footer";
    }
    header{
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 20px;
        grid-area: "header";
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10%;
        background-color: #fa3117e3;
    
    }
    main{
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 20px;
        grid-area: "main";
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10%;
        background-color: #e07924;
    }
    footer{
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 20px;
        grid-area: "footer";
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10%;
        background-color: #6f1adf;
    }
```

app.component.html :

```html
<header>
  <title>
    <h1> THIS IS THE TITLE</h1>
  </title>
</header>

<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practice</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

warning after ng-serve : 
[image]

Comment: Run `npm outdated` and check your versions of PostCSS / autoprefixer, looks like you probably need to update both.

Comment: I've done this. Same warning.
Is this just something not meant to be done with angular ?

Comment: Nah the only relation to angular is that the CLI is using webpack and PostCSS is integrated into the build pipeline, which uses autoprefixer to parse through your css and do things like add `-webkit-transform: *` if you forgot and just wrote `transform: *`, the problem you're running into specifically is support for your declaration of `grid-template-areas` as the error implies which if I recall there were some bugs in older versions that have been since resolved. What version of CLI are you running?

Comment: @angular/cli                  6.2.5

Should I look for the webkit versions of all the grid commands if it's a support issue as you say ?